# How to get application fingerprint for an android app

Tags: java, android, spotify, keytool

I'm trying to use SpotifySDK and I'm following their tutorial. Here they wanted me to get an application fingerprint using keytool, here https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/android/tutorials/application-fingerprints.

I'm using a bash terminal and I'm typing this according to their tutorial:  "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-20\bin\keytool.exe" -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -list -v | grep SHA1

It's asking for a password which I don't know, I tried with random and "changeit" but it's returning nothing. How can I get this SHA fingerprint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried "android" for password and it worked.